# pyodbc - ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: python, odbc

I am running 64-bit Windows 7 and the Python 2.6 installation (64-bit version). 
In addition I am using Aptana Studio 3 to run python.
I just downloaded and installed the pyodbc-3.0.2.win32-py2.6 package.

When I run python and try

```
import pyodbc
```

I receive the following error: 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.'

any idea how do I make it work?

Comment: Anything useful with `python -v` or `python -vv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix the problem by installing pyodbc-2.1.11.win32-py2.6 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/detail?name=pyodbc-2.1.11.win32-py2.6.exe&can=2&q=)

Comment: Did you ever get pyodbc-3.0.2.win32-py2.6 to work?  I'm facing the same issue now with 3.0.7.  pyodbc-2.1.11.win32-py2.6 is working for me but I'd like to use the latest version.

Comment: Sorry but I did not use other version then pyodbc-2.1.11.win32-py2.6

Answer (score 0):

Try the installer for the 64bit version of pyodbc:
http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/detail?name=pyodbc-3.0.2.win-amd64-py2.6.exe&can=2&q=